# Is there anyway to create/terminate objects on an array, or have a render border per object? Or anything to this effect?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, modifiers, loop

I'm using an array on a curve to animate a section of chain. I need the chain links to appear at the start of the curve and disappear at the end. What is the optimal way to achieve this? Here are some examples I made. [image][image]

The obvious solution is to simply loop a cyclic animation (which is what I did to make the examples). The problem is twofold. One, a single section of "loop" for a cyclic animation is long. And two, I have no place to hide the sections of chain that I don't want to be seen. The only solution I can think of is to apply the modifier stack, then keyframe the render toggle on each individual chain link when it reaches the start and end of the curve. There has to be a better way to achieve this effect.

I'll try to upload a .blend with a simple but similar set-up of my use-case.
[image]

Comment: Would a boolean modifier (fast solver difference) added to your chainlink with a mesh surrounding your chain from start to end visibility areas work for you?

Comment: Should work! But shouldn't be 'intersect' rather than 'difference'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the boolean modifier with intersect hides all geo outside of the boolean object's bounds.[image]